# Split into different columns SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, parsing, split

I've got data in a column of my table just like this:

```
cpc > cpc > organic
cpc > organic >cpc
mail > cpc > organic
```

How can I split that data to different columns using '>' as a delimiter?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581772/how-to-split-a-comma-separated-value-to-columns

Comment: So when I use that script in the link- how to make a split function from a certain column? it does not work when i try                                          Select * from fn_CSVToTable (Select Column from Table)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is famous problem. You can use Regex through CLR imported function, but here is very usefull [script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581772/how-to-split-a-comma-separated-value-to-columns). Alter spliting you can use [PIVOT/UNPIVOT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx) is you need exactly data-by-columns.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    PARSENAME(REPLACE(String,'>','.'),1) AS 'col1' ,
    PARSENAME(REPLACE(String,'>','.'),2) AS 'col2' ,
    PARSENAME(REPLACE(String,'>','.'),3) AS 'col3'
FROM tbl
```

Answer (score 0):

may be you can do like this also

```
declare @t table (name varchar(30))
insert into @t (name)values ('cpc > cpc1 > organic'),('cpc > organic1 >cpc')
select 
SUBSTRING(name,0,CHARINDEX('>',name))As Col1,
SUBSTRING(name, charindex('>', name)+1, len(name) - CHARINDEX('>', reverse(name)) - charindex('>', name))As Col2,
REVERSE(SUBSTRING(reverse(name),0,CHARINDEX('>',reverse(name))))As Col3
 from @t
```